# Swift3: Live UiLabel update on user input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a clear answer on updating a label in real-time.

How do i go about updating a `UILabel` (real-time) without the use of a button. For example, i have a text field and a `UIlabel` connected to the `view controller`.

As soon as the user starts typing in the `textfield`, the same text is being displayed in real time on the UI label. As a result,this **eliminates** the use of a **button** to update the label. How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Simply implement UITextFieldDelegate method and update your label in that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the delegate method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    label.text = textField.text
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are update your label in textField `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` Delegate method :

```
   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

      // Update Your label here......

     YourLabel.text = textField.text 
     return true
 }
```

Comment: @LinusG. Now Updated with Swift 3.

Comment: @LinusG. Oky Thanks , But You can Also edit my answer if you found.

Answer (score 1):

option 1: Directly you can make action of textfield with value changed

[image]

```
@IBAction func textFieldValueChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
        self.label.text = sender.text
    }
```

option 2: Give Delegate to TextField

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

     label.text = textField.text 
     return true
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

step 1:Extend class to **UITextFieldDelegate**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
```

> In ViewDidLoad()

Step 2: Add Following code into **ViewDidLoad()**

```
txtDemo.delegate = self

txtDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LabelChanged(_:)), for:.editingChanged)
```

step 3: Make new Function as below:

```
func LabelChanged(_ sender:Any) {
    lblDemo.text = txtDemo.text
}
```

> Or Also use delegate method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    lblDemo.text = txtDemo.text
    return true
}
```

Here **lblDemo** is UILabel outlet and **txtDemo** is UITextField outlet